# Graphs in space efficient representation

Tags: data-structures, space-complexity

Let $G$ be a graph such that $V$ denotes a vertex set and $E$ is an edge set of the graph $G$. Let us consider that for the input graph $G$ it is the case that $|E| \le O(|V| \log |V|)$. Given a graph $G$, I want to answer whether $(u,v) \in E$. If the input graph is given by adjacency representation then I can answer whether $(u,v) \in E$ in $O(\log |V|)$ time with space complexity $O(|V| \log |V|)$.

Space complexity refers to the space taken by input in words. One word means $O(\log |V|)$ bits.

**Question:** Does there exists a representation of graph $G$ such that I can answer whether $(u,v) \in E$ in $o(\log |V|)$ time with space complexity $O(|V|)$?

Answer (score 1):

Farzan and Monroe, [Succinct Representations of Arbitrary Graphs](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4f83/baa1ae2e6eb0f219b458b6bea7c4467e5811.pdf), give such a representation with *constant* query time. See their Theorem 8.